# What is the purpose of giving reputation to existing users when they join new SE sites anymore?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we get rep points on associating our accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56461/why-do-we-get-rep-points-on-associating-our-accounts)

What is the purpose of giving reputation to existing users when they join new SE sites anymore?

With 100 reputation I can't downvote questions and I can't create new tags. What purpose does it matter that I get this reputation now, that I can comment?

Without being able to downvote and add new tags it almost seems pointless to value that people are existing stack exchange members. You might as well just start them at 0 then.

Comment: Sidenote: Reputation is what you are referring to. Flair refers to the account summary image. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134973/?tab=flair

Answer (score 7):

The +100 isn't designed to transfer over your entire reputation -- after all, each site is its own community -- but instead give you [many of the privileges you're used to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) based on the idea that you're not a spammer or completely new at this.

If you're not willing to put in the work it takes to get another 25 points to earn downvotes, then you're probably not really *part* of that community anyway.

Comment: +1 Clear explanation

Answer (score 4):

With 101 reputation you can upvote, comment everywhere, flag posts and edit CW posts. You're also not subject to the new user restrictions (limited number of links in post, ...) any more.

Starting from 1 reputation would be very annoying, I consider it very useful to have the very basic privileges on any SE site.

Creating tags is a dangerous privilege for new users, as they are not yet familiar with the site. It makes a lot of sense to restrict that to the more experienced users.

Comment: From having attempted to use new stack exchange sites just recently I have found it already very annoying with the new limitations that I really don't recall being this heavyhanded. Honestly it just means that myself, and other people are just disincentivized to do anything but the 1 site they care most about.